# Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, microsoft-access

> All of the suggestions [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818354/how-to-resolve-azure-windows-logins-are-not-supported-in-this-version-of-sql-se) are already tried.

Inside our Azure Windows Server 2012 VM, we've got an Azure SQL database. The ODBC connection string obtained from the Azure portal is:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:databaseDomain.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DB_Name;Uid=user-id;Pwd=password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Also, there is an [MS Access application with linked tables](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/connecting-microsoft-access-to-sql-azure/)

The forms in this [app connects to the linked tables through a DSN](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/connecting-microsoft-access-to-sql-azure/). The DSN is created as follows:

In the ODBC Data Sources:

[image: ODBC Data Sources]

SQL Server Native Client 11.0 is selected

[image: SQL Server Native Client 11.0 is selected]

Azure SQL Server connection is set

[image: Azure SQL Server connection is set]

Notice that Windows login is strictly not used

[image: Notice that Windows login is strictly not used]

The databases pops up correctly

[image: The databases pops up correctly]

In the next step, we do everything with defaults

[image: In the next step, we do everything with defaults]

The ODBC DSN setup seems to be succesfull

[image: The ODBC DSN setup seems to be succesfull]

In the Access app's VBA code, we've updated the above connection string as well

[Under Database Tools -> VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec3i6.png):

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:databaseDomain.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DB_Name;Uid=user-id;Pwd=password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

When any of the linked tables is hovered over, the DSN details shows up properly:

[image: DSN details]

However, when any of the linked tables is tried to be opened, the following error is thrown:

[image: Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server]

Notice that Windows login is strictly not used, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we had the same problem. The answer for me was that my tables needed to be relinked after migrating my database to Azure.

If you create a database in Access using an ODBC connection, the tables are linked to the SQL server using a string of information from the last system they were modified and saved on. For my tables, they had been modified on multiple different systems over the years but all of the systems were using Windows Integrated logins.

I held down <kbd>shift</kbd> while opening the Access-based application I had created in order to open it so I could see all of the tables/queries/forms/etc on the left-hand side.

Then, I switched to view the tables form the menu on the upper left-hand side. Then, I right-clicked on a table (any table will do) in order to open "Linked Table Manager".

In linked table manager, I clicked "Select All" hit "OK" and then opened the wizard. I created a DSN file with my credentials for the ODBC connection and then linked every table to that file. I was able to open everything as normal after that. Re-linking takes a long time but it was the only way I could figure out to fix this.